# Ocaml Simplify expression Function

Tags: ocaml

Here is the instructions that I have.

simplify: expression -> expression

such that given an expression e, simplify e reduces it to its simplest polynomial form by combining like terms by adding or subtracting their coefficients. simplifying expressions involving multiplication, distributing the terms if necessary. Arranging the terms in descending order of degrees (from highest to lowest). Ensuring that the polynomial is in the form ax^n+bx^(n−1)+…+cx+d where a , b , c and d are constants. If the coefficient of any monomial is 0, that term is omitted from the final expression.

Examples:

3∗x∗x+2∗x−5+4∗x∗x−7∗x should be reduced to 7∗x∗x−5∗x−5.

(x−1)∗(x∗(x−5) should be reduced to 1∗x∗x∗x−6∗x∗x+5∗x .

x−x should be reduced to 0 .

```
(*ast.ml*)
type binop = Add | Sub | Mul 

type expression =
  | Num of float
  | Var
  | Binop of binop * expression * expression
```

```
open List
open Ast
open ExpressionLibrary

type 'a tree = Leaf | Node of 'a tree * 'a * 'a tree

let rec insert tree x =
  match tree with
  | Leaf -> Node(Leaf, x, Leaf)
  | Node(l, y, r) ->
     if x = y then tree
     else if x < y then Node(insert l x, y, r)
     else Node(l, y, insert r x)

let construct l =
  List.fold_left (fun acc x -> insert acc x) Leaf l

let rec simplify (e: expression) : expression =
  match e with
  | Binop (Add, e1, e2) ->
      (match (simplify e1, simplify e2) with
      | (Num n1, Num n2) -> Num (n1 +. n2)
      | (Num 0., e) -> e
      | (e, Num 0.) -> e
      | (e1', e2') -> Binop (Add, e1', e2'))
  | Binop (Sub, e1, e2) ->
      (match (simplify e1, simplify e2) with
      | (Num n1, Num n2) -> Num (n1 -. n2)
      | (e, Num 0.) -> e
      | (e1', e2') -> Binop (Sub, e1', e2'))
  | Binop (Mul, e1, e2) ->
      (match (simplify e1, simplify e2) with
      | (Num n1, Num n2) -> Num (n1 *. n2)
      | (e, Num 0.) -> Num 0.
      | (Num 0., e) -> Num 0.
      | (e1', e2') -> Binop (Mul, e1', e2'))
  | _ -> e;;
  
let print_simplified_expression expr_str =
  let simplified_expr = simplify (parse expr_str) in
  let stringified_expr = to_string_wo_paren simplified_expr in
  print_string stringified_expr;
  print_newline ();
;;

print_simplified_expression "3*x*x + 2*x - 5 + 4*x*x - 7*x";
print_simplified_expression "(x-1)*x*(x-5)";
print_simplified_expression "x - x";
print_simplified_expression "x + x + 0";
print_simplified_expression "0";
```

For the output, I got

```
3.*x*x+2.*x-5.+4.*x*x-7.*x
x-1.*x*x-5.
x-x
x+x
0.
```

But it's supposed to be

```
7.*x*x+-5.*x+-5.
1.*x*x*x+-6.*x*x+5.*x
0
2.*x
0
```

I don't think simplification is working well, it just deletes 0 and parentheses. Please help me if my approach is wrong

Comment: Style note: `fun acc x -> insert acc x` is directly equivalent to `insert`.

Answer (score 0):

Your rules do not converge towards normalized expressions indeed.

The fix is to clarify what is a normalized expression.

In a typed language like OCaml, one good way to do it is by designing the right type for normalized expression, by making non-valid terms impossible to write.

For instance, the normal form of a polynomial consists in a map between degrees and the value of the coefficients for those degrees.

```ml
module Int_map = Map.Make(Int)
type scalar = float
type polynomial = scalar Int_map
```

With this simplified representation, a polynomial is always in its simplest form because there are no room left for anything else.

Then, if you write a function

```ml
val normalize: expression -> polynomial
val as_expression: polynomial -> expression
```

you will have by construction a simplify function:

```ml
let simplify x = as_expression (normalize x)
```

The other option is to specify precisely what is a normalized expression. In particular, when is a multiplication (resp. an addition) between two normalized expression still a normalized expression?